# Angular - Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ICandidate'.ngt

Tags: angular

I have a code using Angular-12. It's as shown below:

Interface:

```
export interface ICandidate {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  other_name: string;
  last_name : string;
  email: string;
  gender : string;
  user_photo: any;
  marital_status: string;
  dob : Date;
  address : string;
  cv_file: any;
  achievement: IAchievement[];
  certificate: ICertificate[];
  education: IEducation[];
  experience: IExperience[];
  skills: ISkill[];
}
```

candidate.service:

```
import { ICandidate, IAchievement, ICertificate, IEducation, IExperience, ISkill } from '../models/candidate.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CandidateService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private token: TokenService,
    private api: ApiService
  ) { }

  private candidateDetails!: ICandidate;

  getCandidateDetails(): ICandidate {
    return this.candidateDetails;
  }

  setCandidateDetails(candidateDetails: ICandidate): void {
    this.candidateDetails = candidateDetails;
  }

  getCandidateProfile(): Observable<ICandidate> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', this.token.get());
    const url: string = this.api.baseURL + 'display';
    return this.http.get<ICandidate>(url, { headers });
  }
}
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CandidateService } from 'src/app/features/driver/services/candidate.service';
import { ICandidate } from 'src/app/features/driver/models/candidate.model';
import { AppState } from 'src/app/store/reducers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-list',
  templateUrl: './profile-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-list.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileListComponent implements OnInit {

  public loggedIn!: boolean;

  candidateDetails!: ICandidate;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromStore.AppState>,
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private token: TokenService,
    private api : ApiService,
    private candidateService: CandidateService,
    ) {
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.candidateService.getCandidateProfile().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.candidateDetails = response;
        console.log(this.candidateDetails);
        this.candidateService.setCandidateDetails(this.candidateDetails);
      });
  }
}
```

When I did console.log(response); in component, I got:

```
{
  "message": "Profile Successfully Retrieved.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "profile": {
        "id": 2,
        "user_type": "Teacher",
        "created_at": "2021-07-07T07:19:13.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-15T09:57:48.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "last_login_at": "2021-07-15T09:57:48.000000Z",
        "detail": {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 2,
            "first_name": "Lamptey",
            "last_name": "Akwetey",
            "other_name": null,
            "email": "lamptey@yahoo.com",
            "gender": null,
            "user_photo": null,
            "marital_status": null,
            "dob": null,
            "address": null,
            "cv_file": null,
            "summary": null,
            "created_at": "2021-07-07T07:19:13.000000Z",
            "updated_at": null
        },
        "educations": [],
        "experiences": [],
        "achievements": [],
        "certificates": [],
        "skills": [],
        "employees": []
    }
}
```

profile and detail have single data.

Now I want to display the profile, detail, educations and experiences

> {{ candidateDetails.results.profile.user_type }}

gives this error:

> Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ICandidate'.ngt

Likewise

{{ candidateDetails.results.profile.detail.first_name }}

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: return this.http.get<ICandidate>(url, { headers }).pipe(map(response => response.results.profile))

Comment: As @MikeOne mentioned in my answer, the response doesn't seem to match the interface defined. Eg. there is no `results` property in the interface. Once it's fixed, you could use the safe navigation operator: `{{ candidateDetails?.results?.profile?.user_type }}` to check if a variable is defined before trying to access it's properties. Or do `{{ candidateDetails.results.profile.user_type || '-' }}` to display something else (like the `-`) when any of the property is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your provided JSON result and `getCandidateProfile` in candidate.service.ts, you cannot cast it to `ICandidate`  as the JSON result doesn't match with the `ICandidate` template. Instead, `ICandidate` is *a small part* of the JSON.

Your interfaces should look as below:

> response.model.ts

```js
export interface IResponse<T> {
  message: string;
  error: boolean,
  code: number,
  results: T;
}
```

> candidate.model.ts

```js
export interface IProfile {
  profile: ICandidate;
}

export interface ICandidate {
  id: number;
  user_type: string;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
  deleted_at: string;
  last_login_at: string;
  detail: ICandidateDetail;
  achievement: IAchievement[];
  certificate: ICertificate[];
  education: IEducation[];
  experience: IExperience[];
  skills: ISkill[];
}

export interface ICandidateDetail {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  other_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
  gender: string;
  user_photo: any;
  marital_status: string;
  dob: Date;
  address: string;
  cv_file: any;
}
```

Meanwhile, I recorrect your `ICandidate` by adding `detail: ICandidateDetail` which `ICandidateDetails` hold the properties such as `first_name`, `last_name` and etc. to match with your JSON template.

> candidate.service.ts

```js
getCandidateProfile(): Observable<IResponse<IProfile>> {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Authorization', this.token.get());
  const url: string = this.api.baseURL + 'display';
  return this.http.get<IResponse<IProfile>>(url, { headers });
}
```

And also you may review the variable naming and type such as `candidate` and `candidateDetail` to avoid confusion.

> profile-list.component.ts

```
export class ProfileListComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  candidate!: ICandidate;
  candidateDetail!: ICandidateDetail;

  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.candidateService.getCandidateProfile().subscribe(
      (response: IResponse<IProfile>) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.candidate = response.results.profile;
        this.candidateDetail = response.results.profile.detail;
        this.candidateService.setCandidateDetails(this.candidate);
      });
  }
}
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lkff1j)

Answer (score 0):

The response is of type ICandidate, as you wrote in the candidate.service file:  `getCandidateProfile(): Observable<ICandidate>` and you assign the entire response to candidateDetails as you did here: `this.candidateDetails = response;`

Your ICandidate interface has these properties:

```
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  other_name: string;
  last_name : string;
  email: string;
  gender : string;
  user_photo: any;
  marital_status: string;
  dob : Date;
  address : string;
  cv_file: any;
  achievement: IAchievement[];
  certificate: ICertificate[];
  education: IEducation[];
  experience: IExperience[];
  skills: ISkill[];
```

You get that error because your response doesn't have the same properties as your ICandidate interface.

You also have an extra "details" parameter in your response. You should set your backend to return the data in the same way you configured it in the ICandidate interface and when the properties are the same and also named the same you will be fine.

At first I thought the "detail" parameter contained all the parameters defined in ICandidate, but then I saw they are not the same, for example these parameters are missing

```
 "educations": [],
 "experiences": [],
 "achievements": [],
 "certificates": [],
 "skills": [],
```

So one step will be to put in the "detail" all the data needed for the ICandidate interface and then you can set the data like this in the response:
`this.candidateDetails = response.results.profile.details`.

Comment: I put this in the component response:        this.candidateDetails = response.results.profile.details;     but got this error:       error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ICandidate'.